# Couldn't run the code that contains sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm using Postgresql and I'm trying to run the below code in cmd (py list.py) terminal but I couldn't, it is showing:

**Error Message:**

```
  File "list.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'
```

I need help as I tried to run this in the virtual environment directory (pip install sqlalchemy) and then still showing the same error message!

**Code:**

```
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

def main():
    flights = db.execute("SELECT origin, destination, duration FROM flights").fetchall()
    for flight in flights:
        print(f"{flight.origin} to {flight.destination}, {flight.duration} minutes.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Can you check if sqlalchemy is installed by from the pip3 freeze command. And also please make sure the virtual environment is activated when running the file ,if you are using a virtual environment .If you are using python3, to install use  pip3 install SQLAlchemy

Comment: Hi, I already installed it, but still showing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Finally!!, I found the answer in this helpful page: https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/30610/cs50w-list-py-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-instantia , after that you need to type this command:

```
pip3 install Psycopg2
```

you will be connected to the database successfully.